# dimension confusion when using dp units to place images at specific locations

Tags: android, android-layout

OK, so imagine that you have a background image (scaled to fill the entire width/height of the device) that contains some random art and two rectangles.  Now, if I want to place an image in each rectangle, I don't see how I can use dp units to do so.  From the Android documents:

> For instance, a view with a
>   layout_width="100dp" measures 100
>   pixels wide on medium-density screen
>   and the system scales it up to 150
>   pixels wide on high-density screen, so
>   that the view occupies approximately
>   the same physical space on the screen.

The problem that I see is that if I have two devices that are the same resolution, but one is medium density and the other is high density, the high density image would be scaled too big.

Does that mean that the only option available for guaranteeing that images are the same size regardless of density/resolution is to incorporate conversion functions?  That seems to go against the reason dp exists, which leads me to believe that I am understanding this incorrectly.  Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If the two devices have the same resolution, but different densities, then the screen sizes will be different, so yes, the images will be scaled differently. This is probably what you want, since the background real size will also depend on the screen size.

If, for some reason, you want to set the images to a specific size instead, regardless of densities and resolutions, then use the size units `in` (inches) or `mm` (millimeters).

**Edit**: if they have the same size and different densities, then they have different resolutions, and thus you can't use px to set the right size. You still need to take the density into consideration to use the same amount of screen. Besides that, with different resolutions then you have the option to create layouts for each one, namely: `res/layout-normal`, `res/layout-large`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aleadam.  Sorry, I meant two devices with the same screen size, but different densities.  If I use in or mm then it wouldn't be sized properly on devices with different screen sizes if I wanted to size it for both tablets and phones.

Comment: Then I'll reply you with the same reasoning, backwards. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is one of the more confusing parts of Android development.

If, for the same resolution, device A is medium density and device B is high density, device A would be physically larger then device B.

To put further numbers to this, lets say the mdpi bg image was 100x100 pixels and that we were trying to place a rectangle from 10,10 to 15,15. If we define the offset in terms of px, here is what we would get:

device A(mdpi): bg image is 100x100px, offset is 10px x 10px

device B(hdpi): bg image is 150x150px, offset is 10px x 10px

If instead, the offset is in dp, the results would be:

device A(mdpi): bg image is 100x100px, offset is 10px x 10px

device B(hdpi): bg image is 150x150px, offset is **15px x 15px**

The beauty of dp is that they are scaled proportionally with your other drawables.

**Update:** per your response to Aleadam, you circumvent this problem by providing different art assets in drawable, drawable-hdpi per the instructions [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)